# PHP TCPDF: emebdding images is very slow

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am facing an issue with TCPDF. 
On XAMPP installation, suddenly, embedding images takes more than 10 secs.

Sample code is as follows:

```
    $image_file = __DIR__ . '/img/LOGO.jpg';
    $img = file_get_contents($image_file);

    // This line takes 11 secs
    $this->Image('@' . $img, 15, 5, 30);
```

This used to work fine with good speed.
Now suddenly it became very slow.

Any ideas?

Update: I have profiled the code and found out tempnam is taking very long. Like 65.000 files on the temp directory. Could that be the problem?

Comment: `On XAMPP installation, suddenly` does that mean you used to use an other AMP before ?

Comment: Means it worked very good for some time, say 6 months, now suddenly the performance got very degradated!

Comment: For no reason ? No major change ? because it looks to be a really basic operation to TCPDF. Also some change on your environment ? XAMPP upgrade, computer performance down ? Is it generate to be display on the browser or to be downloadable ? To be honest it could be thousands of reason. Will be hard to help you

Comment: By the way why are you using the `image data stream` feature instead of the file one ? I mean, did you try to use `$this->Image($image_file, 15, 5, 30);` instead of `$this->Image('@' . $img, 15, 5, 30);`

Comment: Customer says "no reason"... Yes, I know it is difficult to help.. I will keep on debugging and timing to see what command is taking so long...

Comment: @Frankich I am using image data stream, yes. It is actually similar, as one of the first things Image method does is load the data stream.

Comment: I have profiled the code and found out tempnam is taking very long. Like 65.000 files on the temp directory. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks to bring stuff i did not now :). I found on the doc that `On NTFS this also happens if the specified dir contains more than 65534 files. ` it `it falls back on the system default`. So It's mostly probably the case. I can't test it right now but I'll try this evening (Europe). I think I won't be suprised to find out that even count 40000 files on windows file system takes some time. Maybe you could just move all those file (or change the dir of tempnam) just to check if it solve the problem. And by the way, 65000 file in a folder /o\

Comment: Ok, so it seems to work better now! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: So I keep on reviewing and found out thoe temp files were generated by TCPDF and somehow were not removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After profiling the code, found the problem was related to the `tempnam` function, called inside the TCPDF library. It was taking like 20 secs.

Dived into the TCPDF temp folder and saw 65.000 files in it. Those temporary files were created by TCPDF but not cleaned up. So after heavy usage, XAMPP performance got degradated when needing to write in that folder.

After moving those temp files out, everything seemed to work great!

Comment: Do you allow me to edit ? I was busy sorry. If you are ok with the edit, I'll do it this week end, I'm in a middle of a house move at the moment. But I was thinking to do some performance test, explain why this limitation of 65534 files on NTFS, stuff like this

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to check out that worked for me was to use the rest of the Image function settings to shrink the image before writing it onto the PDF

```
Image( $file, $x = '', $y = '', $w = 0, $h = 0, $type = '', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = false, $dpi = 300, $palign = '', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = false, $alt = false, $altimgs = array() );
```

Setting resize to true and the DPI to 72 changed a PDF from taking 110 seconds down to 2.5 seconds for me